# midi in + audio out on iPhone 7?

Tags: headphones, iphone, midi

I'm trying to replicate the setup I used with my iPhone 6 for music production.

On iPhone 6, I was able to have

- midi input from a digital piano, via lightning port
- audio output to a mixer, via headphones jack

Is there a way to do this on iPhone 7, perhaps with a 3rd party adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a USB midi keyboard and the lightning camera adapter for MIDI? If so, this probably won't work for you...  However, if you're just using standard MIDI ports, you might be able to use [this](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/iRigProDuo), although no guarantees, as I haven't tested it.  It has headphone outputs and MIDI inputs, so **in theory** you should be able to do what you need.

EDIT: Just thought of this: You might be able to do this with a lightning to USB adapter, a powered USB hub, a class compliant USB MIDI interface, and a class compliant USB to 3.5mm audio interface.  Theoretically this should work since all these devices are supported, however this hasn't been tested by me.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the lightning camera adapter. My keyboard has both USB midi and regular midi outputs so this thing might work, I'll take a look, though I was hoping for something under $50 :-/

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it's correct, although *my* actual solution is to use my old iphone6. I also considered buying a used iPad)